# Remove attic 1x4 bracing in 1950s house

Tags: roof, attic, support

New to the forum, so please let me know if there's any other info that would be helpful here.  I'm currently a DIYer, but have been in construction on and off for 10yrs, but never on the structural/engineering side.

I've attached a pic of the attic in my 1950s home where I'm looking to create a loft/playroom area.  This will *not* be considered living space, its intended to be a way to get all of the legos out of our living room so I stop stepping on them :-)

My question: what is the structural purpose of - and can I remove - the 1x4 diagonal bracing between the rafters and the joists.  They are placed throughout the attic perpendicular to the rafters at regular intervals.  They do *not* rest on load bearing walls in most places.  My hope is to remove at the two marked in yellow, the ones that meet them from the opposite side (dotted yellow) as well as the set of them in the foreground (also in yellow) to create enough space for a roughly 15x15 "room."  The diagonal braces are 1x4 (rough sawn) lumber; the rafters, joists, and vertical supports are true 2x4.

The vertical supports (in green) *do* often rest on a load-bearing wall and I do not intend on removing any of those, but may need to relocate several within 18" of their current location.

Also, that's an old water heater to the right, which will also be fun to take out :-)

Thanks in advance for any advice/opinions.

[image]

Comment: Not an engineer, so can’t possibly predict a change to framing (even if I had the whole picture, which is kinda necessary). What I can predict is that little Lego-players will jump around enough to crack your plaster and lath ceiling. Buzzkill, I know — sorry!

Comment: Your assumption is in the 1950s they had extra lumber they installed for just for fun? All kidding aside, this was not designed to support the weight of flooring and people. It probably won't fall in, but it would be bouncy and as the other comment mentions, the plaster will be cracking, at the very least.

Comment: Certainly looks like a site-built truss bracing arrangement, using the full-sized 1x4 in the tension members (not unreasonable for the era) which means you don't want to mess with it without consulting an engineer first, because you'll be betting your house on whatever you do not making the roof collapse.

Comment: As for "not considered living space, but your children will play there" exactly how cheaply do you count their lives? Most of the things that differentiate "purely for storage" and "living space" are life safety considerations. People living in storage areas sometimes die for that distinction.